# How to edit content in WordPress and the Polylang – plugin? – with demosite

Tags: php, mysql, apache, linux

hello dear user, hello dear developer,

the question; How to edit content in WordPress and the Polylang - plugin?

first of all: i love PolyLang for its powerful features and the versatile options of customization. Perhaps i have overseen some things - but at the moment i struggle. i set up  a site with several langauges - which is in a beta mode: at the moment i have only little text-chunks in German and English...

btw: default is German

if i add  in the Polylang-controll field a new translation the this will create a new entity in the db - and the funny thing  it is imitiately visible at the top menu - why is this so !?

**see the following**: 
- german: http://www.job-starter.com/?page_id=75 :: JOBS & CHANCEN IN DEUTSCHLAND
- english: http://www.job-starter.com/?page_id=157&lang=en :: JOBS & CHANCES IN GERMANY (ENGLISH)

see the page: http://www.job-starter.com  - which is a truely beta-beta-page: and have a close look at the menu. - here you see both languages. This is somewhat disturbing and irritating - making me feel annoyed

question: how to surpress the behaviour that both (!!!) languages are visible in the menu.

look forward to hear from you

regards

ps; Keep up the great work  - it rocks and PolyLang is generally a really powerful plugin - very very flexible and versatile.

Comment: maybe you don't have defined menus (https://wordpress.org/support/article/appearance-menus-screen/) you need 1 menu for each language.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a menu in Appearance > Menus for each language.
See more here: https://polylang.pro/doc/create-menus/